# How to process a subset of input records in a batch, i.e. the first second in 3-sec batch time?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

If I set `Seconds(1)` for the batch time in `StreamingContext`, like this:

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(1))
```

3 seconds will receive the 3 seconds of data, but I only need the first seconds of data, I can discard the next 2 seconds of data. So can I spend 3 seconds to process only first second of data?

Comment: Better would be to capture 3 seconds of data and then filter/ process only relevant dataset. But need some more details about the problem statement before any comments upon solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this via `updateStateByKey` if you keep track of counter, for example like below:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ConstantInputDStream
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}

object StreamEveryThirdApp {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val sc = new SparkContext("local[*]", "Streaming Test")
    implicit val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(1))
    ssc.checkpoint("./checkpoint")

    // generate stream
    val inputDStream = createConstantStream

    // increase seconds counter
    val accStream = inputDStream.updateStateByKey(updateState)

    // keep only 1st second records
    val firstOfThree = accStream.filter { case (key, (value, counter)) => counter == 1}

    firstOfThree.print()

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()

  }

  def updateState: (Seq[Int], Option[(Option[Int], Int)]) => Option[(Option[Int], Int)] = {
    case(values, state) =>
      state match {
        // If no previous state, i.e. set first Second
        case None => Some(Some(values.sum), 1)
        // If this is 3rd second - remove state
        case Some((prevValue, 3)) => None
        // If this is not the first second - increase seconds counter, but don't calculate values
        case Some((prevValue, counter)) => Some((None, counter + 1))
    }
  }

  def createConstantStream(implicit ssc: StreamingContext): ConstantInputDStream[(String, Int)] = {
    val seq = Seq(
      ("key1", 1),
      ("key2", 3),
      ("key1", 2),
      ("key1", 2)
    )
    val rdd = ssc.sparkContext.parallelize(seq)
    val inputDStream = new ConstantInputDStream(ssc, rdd)
    inputDStream
  }
}
```

In case if you have time information within your data, you could also use 3 seconds window `stream.window(Seconds(3), Seconds(3))` and filter records by the time information from data, and quite often this is preferred approach

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have another one question: Is there API like _updateState_ and not _updateStateByKey()_? _updateStateByKey()_ only used for tuple2 like (k, v), when I have some data's type of **String**, what can I do? adding different key for data?

Comment: There is no API without key, so you will need to add one. Normally you can define a key as a combination of some data elements. Better yet, you could add a key in the source system. In all data processing jobs (not only in spark) you want to have data lineage from very first source to final destination, so adding key early if possible at all - is a good practice in general

Comment: Alternatively if you cannot define key at all or don't want to aggregate data - you can try to use timestamp `time` in `foreachRDD` and process only by condition similar to `time % 3 == 0`

Comment: Is there a reason that `updateState` is a `def` not `val`?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski - initially for no reason, but this is good thought-provoking question :)  Do you believe that using def here will have negative impact on Spark serialization of the function or something else? I stumbled upon mentions of recommendations to use vals for Spark previously, but couldn't find it now.

Comment: `def` is part of an object while `val` is an already-computed value that can have an impact on *what* Spark is supposed to serialize (and sent to workers). I'm more for `val`s in general :)