# How to use updateStateByKey() with using socketTextStream in spark streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

## 1st testing:

the code for testing below:

```
object StreamTest {

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val sc = new SparkContext
        val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(1))
        ssc.checkpoint("./checkpoint")

        val lines = ssc.socketTextStream("192.168.11.5", 9999, StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER)
        val accStream = lines.map((_ , "")).updateStateByKey(updateFunc)
        accStream.print()
        ssc.start()
        ssc.awaitTermination()
    }
    def updateFunc: (Seq[String], Option[Int]) => Option[Int] = { case _ => Some(1) }
}
```

When I send one data(only one) by NetCat, see screenshot:
[image]

***the result is:***

[image]

My question is: why the result is printed all the time? Why not one time? (I only send one data to socket client.)

## 2nd testing:

I'm testing again(set spark streaming interval time to 5 seconds):

**send data:**

[image]

**the result is:**

[image]

## 3rd tesing:

Using `ConstantInputDStream` for tesing, code below:

```
object SparkStreaming {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val sc = new SparkContext
        val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(1))
        ssc.checkpoint("./checkpoint")
        val seq = Seq("key")   //every 1 second send a "key"
        val rdd = ssc.sparkContext.parallelize(seq)
        //using ConstantInputDStream as inputDStream
        val inputDStream = new ConstantInputDStream(ssc, rdd)

        val map = inputDStream.map((_, "")).updateStateByKey(updateFunc)
        map.print
        ssc.start
        ssc.awaitTermination
    }

    def updateFunc: (Seq[String], Option[Int]) => Option[Int] = { case _ => Some(1) }
}
```

**the result is:**

[image]

the result of 3rd testing is **the same to** result of 1st testing.

**In 1st test**, I only send a "key" in **the 1st second**.

**In 3rd test**, ConstantInputDStream send "key" **every 1 second**.

but why the results is the same? So the result is really odd with using `socketTextStream`.

Could you tell me why? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of `updateStateByKey` is to save and accumulate state when needed. After `updateStateByKey` your stream is set of tuples with keys and returned values from your update function. It will keep state of the key until you return `None` from your update function instead of `Some`.

You can refer to the example implementation in this answer: [How to process a subset of input records in a batch, i.e. the first second in 3-sec batch time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34937394/can-i-spend-more-time-than-interval-time-to-process-data-in-sparkstreaming/34995834#34995834)

Comment: I update my question, can you see again? I know `updateStateByKey` is to save and accumulate state, but in my case, `updateStateByKey` not only saved state but also saved my data and printed data repeatedly. In website of your provide, it use `ConstantInputDStream`, the problem is disappeared, `ConstantInputDStream` will send data all the time, so the result will be printed all the time, but in my case with using `socketTextStream`, I send data once, the result should be printed once. I need save state, but I needn't save previous data. Thank you!

Comment: After stream goes thru `updateStateByKey` it becomes `StateDStream` which stores your state for each key it sees, until it is explicitly removed (by returning `None` for key in your update function). So in your 2nd test it is very evident that it adds each key as soon as it sees it, and never removes it, as you don't return None in your update function. Again, this is intended behaviour. If you want to see your actual data and not their state you still can do `lines.map((_ , "")).print`

Comment: I update the question for the 3rd testing and using `ConstantInputDStream`.

Comment: I have been misunderstood! Thank you for your help! And now, I got it!

Answer (score 1):

That is because of `updateStateByKey` Saves your state and does not update unless  new feeds are processed.

Comment: But when I change `socketTextStream` to `ConstantInputDStream`, this problem is disappeared.  How to avoid it with `socketTextStream`?

Comment: That is not the problem, it is the intended behavior. Mostly people use `ConstantInputDStream` for testing and replicating Streaming Data and not for consuming real streaming data from sources. May be you can give some example of how you are using and I can try providing the reason for the behavior. Secondly,  If you do not want to save the state then do not use `updateStateByKey` operation, you can leverage other aggregate functions but you cannot avoid the saving the state with `updateStateByKey`.

Comment: this case is for tesing, in fact I need use `updateStateByKey` to achieve some functions. I update my question, can you see again? I need save state, but I needn't save previous data. obviously, the result of second testing is very strange.

Comment: it is really odd that it doesn't behave exactly same way for `ConstantInputDStream` as for `socketTextStream` in your code. If you share your code `ConstantInputDStream` - we might find the root cause of such behaviour - as I assume there should be something else causing it

Comment: I update the question for the 3rd testing and using `ConstantInputDStream`.

Comment: I have been misunderstood! Thank you for your help! And now, I got it!